# Detect the screen orientation with the accelerometer SensorEventListener?

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, screen-orientation, android-sensors

I would like to detect the screen orientation when the orientation is set to Portrait by using the accelerometer sensor. I need this to rotate button elements on the screen while the layout remains static. Overriding the OnConfigurationChanged won't work, because the activity is set to portrait. I need to detect the device motion with the sensor and override manually portrait, landscape, reverse portrait and reverse landscape to rotate the buttons on my layout accordingly. I'm open to any other idea as long as it works. Hope you can help me.

Comment: What's the reason for locking the activity to portrait if you do need to change the layout based on orientation? Just curious for the rationale.

Comment: The reason to lock the activity to portrait is that I want my layout to remain static and my buttons to rotate with the orientation sensor and seems that it can't be in any other way. All I need is an accelerometer code for the axis x and y and a way to input actions to each of the orientations. I am a newie and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Rotating a button means that the layout isn't static anymore. I think you're over engineering your solution - have a look at how to properly handle activity recreation and you will find that you can handle what you want without relying on unaccurate accelerator data.

Comment: I think you're right, but I might now have explained myself correctly. If you take a look at VSCO Cam camera activity, you will see a clear example of what I mean. As you rotate the device even when the screen rotation is turned off on my device, their views (buttons and images) will rotate to every angle. I don't think they're using layout land for this. It looks like an animation. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vsco.cam&hl=en

Comment: I know it was like 2 years ago but, @AdrianaCota did you find a solution?

Comment: I know it was like 2 years ago but, @AdrianaCota did you find a solution?